# Get Page Title "Shortcode" in Whatsapp Chat Button

Tags: wordpress, whatsapp

I am trying to Get a Post Title in a Whatsapp Button (I am using CF7 From)

Following is my Button-Link and I am using this CF7 on a custom post type.

https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+00000000000&text=I need Enquiry [title]

Not Even [title], I used all shortcodes, But it passing as href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+00000000000&text=I need Enquiry [title]"

I tried using all mail tag 
Ref: https://contactform7.com/special-mail-tags/

I used Following codes also

```
/*Write here your own functions */ 
function getPageTitle() {
    global $wp_query;
    return get_post_title( $wp_query->post->ID );
}

/* Add shortcode */
add_shortcode( 'page_title', 'getPageTitle' );
```

Want to know what is correct Shortcode for Page Title

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure get_post_title() is a valid function have you tried get_the_title();?

Answer (score 0):

For that, you need to store the title in one variable and then you can pass that variable in the URL